# Maintaining TabBar when performing Segue in the tab item

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tabbed application running with 4 tabbed items.

Each tabbed item has its own view controller - `controller1, controller2, controller3 and controller4`. I can transition to anyone of them without problems.

I now have a new view controller `newView`. I perform a segue from `controller2` to `newView`. Problem is, when I perform the segue, the TabBar disappears in `newView`.

Also, if I segue back, I don't see the tab bar in `controller2` either.

How do I go about this in Swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should wrap each `UIViewController` (`controller1`, `controller2`, `controller3` and `controller4`) in its own `UINavigationController` (in the storyboard you will find the option in Editor > Embed in).
- Each of the four navigation controllers should in turn become tabs in your `UITabBarController`.
- The transition from `controller2` to `newView` will be within its navigation controller, which is enclosed in the tab bar controller and therefore the tab bar controller will not be dismissed.